# Completely reset a dom-repeat element with new data

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

Every once in a while, `<dom-repeat>`'s penchant for trying to be smarter than it needs to be causes problems with property binding, resulting in recycled elements displaying stale or duplicate data.

Regardless of how much `this.splice()`ing or `this.push()`ing you try it seems to do little more than waste cycles as it has zero effect.

At this point doing whatever the documentation tells you to do--which amounts to trying to figure out the correct combination of arcane bindings to subproperties and subarrays, and observer-triggering mutators to get the black magic to work--seems like a waste of effort, and it would be faster and easier to wipe the slate and rebuild the elements from a fresh state. So how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the prior lack of answers in this subject, it turns out that resetting a `<dom-repeat>` is pretty easy. Simply wrap the `<dom-repeat>` in a `<dom-if>` which binds to a `reset` property, which can be freely used to kill and reconstruct the `<dom-repeat>` as necessary.

First, we define the data which needs to be reset.

```html
<iron-ajax id="retrieveData"
           method="get"
           url="/api/data"
           handle-as="json"
           on-response="_handleData">
</iron-ajax>
<template is="dom-if" if="[[!_reset]]">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[veryComplicatedObjects]]">
    <my-complicated-custom-element content={{item}} on-change="_remoteChanged"/>
  </template>
</template>
```

And now we write our event handlers

```js
_remoteChanged() {
  // trigger retrieval of new data
  this.$.retrieveData.generateRequest()
}

_handleData(e) {
  // kill dom-repeat
  this.setProperties({
    veryComplicatedObjects: []
  })
  this._reset = true

  // reconstruct dom-repeat
  this.setProperties({
    veryComplicatedObjects: e.detail.response
  })
  this._reset = false
}
```